# Change color of multiple labels in ajxax jquery and .NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a function that allows users to select answers with a radio button. After selecting all answers, the user clicks Submit and the answer label will display the following 3 cases:

1. When the user selects the correct answer label, the answer will change color to green
2. When the user chooses incorrectly, the answer label turns red and the correct answer label turns green
3. When the user does not select, a green label will be displayed for the correct answer

I am not able to implement the above logic and suspect I am calling the class names wrong!
Please give me a solution, thanks!

This is my code

```
@using WebToeic.WebAppMVC.ViewModels

@model GetDoListenVM


@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewData["Title"] = "Exam";
}



<section class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                
                <form method="post" asp-action="DoListen" asp-controller="UserListen" id="listenForm">
                    @if (Model != null && Model.listenQuestions != null)
                    {
                        @foreach (var item in Model.listenQuestions)
                        {
                            <div class="question">
                                <div class="question-wrapper mb-4">
                                    <div class="row" style="background-color: lightgray;">
                                        @if (item.AudioL != null)
                                        {
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <audio controls style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                                    <source src="~/uploadsAudioListen/@item.AudioL" type="audio/mpeg">
                                                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                                                </audio>
                                            </div>
                                        }

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row" style="background-color: lightgray;">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <p class="font-weight-bold h5">Question @item.Order . @item.Question</p>
                                        </div>
                                        @if (item.Photo != null)
                                        {
                                            <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: lightgray;">
                                                <img src="~/uploadsImageListen/@item.Photo" alt="Question Image" class="img-fluid">
                                            </div>
                                        }

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-start">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <h4>Answers:</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row justify-content-start">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input ml-1 answer" type="radio" name="userAnswers[@item.Id]" id="answer_@item.Id-1" value="A" data-CorrectAnswer="A">
                                                <label class="form-check-label h5 correct-answer-label" for="answer_@item.Id-1">
                                                    @item.Answer1
                                                </label>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-start">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input ml-1 answer" type="radio" name="userAnswers[@item.Id]" id="answer_@item.Id-2" value="B" data-CorrectAnswer="B">
                                                <label class="form-check-label h5 correct-answer-label" for="answer_@item.Id-2">
                                                    @item.Answer2
                                                </label>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-start">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            @if (item.Answer3 != null)
                                            {
                                                <div class="form-check">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input ml-1 answer" type="radio" name="userAnswers[@item.Id]" id="answer_@item.Id-3" value="C" data-CorrectAnswer="C">
                                                    <label class="form-check-label h5 correct-answer-label " for="answer_@item.Id-3">
                                                        @item.Answer3
                                                    </label>

                                                </div>
                                            }
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row justify-content-start">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            @if (item.Answer4 != null)
                                            {
                                                <div class="form-check">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input ml-1 answer" type="radio" name="userAnswers[@item.Id]" id="answer_@item.Id-4" value="D" data-CorrectAnswer="D">
                                                    <label class="form-check-label h5 correct-answer-label" for="answer_@item.Id-4">
                                                        @item.Answer4
                                                    </label>

                                                </div>
                                            }
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row justify-content-start">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="explanation" hidden>
                                                Lời giải thích: @item.Explain
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        }
                    }
                    <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    <!-- Kết quả -->
                    <div id="resultDiv" hidden>
                        <h3>Result</h3>
                        <div id="correctCount"></div>

                    </div>
                </form>

                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {                      
                                       
                        $('#listenForm').submit(function (event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            var formData = new FormData(this);                          

                            // Gửi dữ liệu đến server
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '@Url.Action("DoListen", "UserListen")', // Địa chỉ URL xử lý dữ liệu ở phía server
                                type: 'POST', // Phương thức gửi dữ liệu là POST
                                processData: false, // Kiểu dữ liệu gửi đi là JSON
                                contentType: false,
                                data: formData,//JSON.stringify(userAnswers)//, // Dữ liệu gửi đi được chuyển thành chuỗi JSON
                                success: function (result) {
                                    // Xử lý kết quả trả về từ server Hiển thị kết quả
                               
                                    $("#resultDiv").removeAttr("hidden");;
                                    $("#correctCount").text("Correct: " + result.correctCount);
                                   

                                    // Hiển thị dấu tick và dấu X  result.answers,
                                    $.each(result.answers, function (index, item) {
                                        var questionDiv = $(".question").eq(index);
                                        //var questionDiv = $(this);
                                        var selectedAnswer = questionDiv.find("input[type='radio']:checked");
                                        //var correctAnswer = questionDiv.find("input[type='radio'][value='" + item.CorrectAnswer + "']");
                                        //var correctAnswer = questionDiv.find("input[type='radio'][name='" + userAnswers[item.QuestionId] + "'][value='" + item.CorrectAnswer + "']");
                                        var correctAnswer = questionDiv.find("input[type='radio'][data-CorrectAnswer='" + item.CorrectAnswer + "']");
                                        
                                        if (selectedAnswer.length > 0) {                               
                                            if (selectedAnswer.val() === item.CorrectAnswer) {
                                                //correctAnswer.closest(".question").find("label.answer").css("color", "blue");
                                                //selectedAnswer.siblings("label.answer").css("color", "blue");
                                                correctAnswer.next("label.correct-answer-label").css("color", "blue");
                                            } else {
                                                selectedAnswer.siblings("label.answer").css("color", "red");
                                                //correctAnswer.closest(".question").find("label.answer").css("color", "blue");
                                                correctAnswer.next("label.correct-answer-label").css("color", "blue");
                                                //correctAnswer.siblings("label.answer").css("color", "blue");
                                                
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            //correctAnswer.siblings("label.answer").css("color", "blue");
                                            //correctAnswer.closest(".question").find("label.answer").css("color", "blue");
                                            correctAnswer.next("label.correct-answer-label").css("color", "blue");
                                        }

                                        // Hiển thị phần giải thích
                                        questionDiv.find(".explanation").removeAttr("hidden");;
                                    });
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                    // Xử lý lỗi nếu có
                                }

                            });


                        });
                    });
                </script>
                <hr class="invis">

            </div><!-- end col -->          

        </div><!-- end row -->
    </div><!-- end container -->
</section>
```

Comment: Could you pls share the rendered HTML on the browser, not the template HTML? jQuery code is ok.

Comment: `[data-CorrectAnswer` - make sure all your data- attributes are lowercase in both the HTML and JavaScript

Comment: Hi @ĐÌnh Hiếu Trịnh, any update here?

Comment: Hi @Rena Hello, I came here to ask with little hope so I thought no one would answer, but it's great that your answer helped me solve the problem. You're great, you're a great friend, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naming convention for response json in asp.net core is **camel case** instead of pascal case.

You could add `console.log(result)` to check the response in `Console` panel(press F12 in browser). Then you will find the property name in response is camel case.

You need modify your code `item.CorrectAnswer` to `item.correctAnswer`:

```
var correctAnswer = questionDiv.find("input[type='radio'][data-CorrectAnswer='" + item.correctAnswer + "']");

if (selectedAnswer.length > 0) {                               
    if (selectedAnswer.val() === item.correctAnswer) {
```

BTW, you said it needs turn red if the answer is not correct, I never find the lable with class answer, not sure if you did any other operation to change the class name or not. If not, it should be `correct-answer-label`.

Change the code from:

```
selectedAnswer.siblings("label.answer").css("color", "red")
```

To:

```
selectedAnswer.siblings("label.correct-answer-label").css("color", "red")
```